# Matching possibility of space followed by graph sequence

Tags: awk

I want to match the possibility of a space followed by graph class

I am using the following pattern

```
^[[:space:]]?[[:graph:]]*$
```

over a previous one which was

```
^.*$
```

I think the former is more specific than the latter.

I want to match the rule that the start of the graph characters has to be preceded by a space for a match to occur.  Thusly, my improved version would still need some final tweaking.

So basically one or more graph characters preceded by space; or nothing (empty).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Whether `^[[:space:]]?[[:graph:]]*$` is more exact than just `^.*$`.  I want to match a space followed by text, where both the space and the text could be optional.

Comment: Yes `^[[:space:]]?[[:graph:]]*$` is definitely more specific as it won't match if there are trailing spaces or control characters but `.*` will match anything.

Comment: I don't think `[[:graph:]]` covers the same chars included in `[[:alpha:]]` . You need to learn how to test this sort of problem at the cmd-line, maybe `echo "a1 |c" | awk '{if ($0 ~/[[:space:]]?[[:graph:]]*$/){print "matched"} else print "no match" }'` ...  **output** : `matched` ... gives you a place to start.

Comment: Recall that predefined "named" character classes ( `[[:alpha:]]`) are really short hand for character class ranges, i.e. `[[A-Za-z]]`. You need to find out what the range of characters are covered by `[[:graph:]]` . Your reg-ex with `[[:space:]]?[[:graph:]]*` will only match `:graph:` characters with an optional space preceding. Almost certainly not `[[:alpha:]]` or any of the others.  Sorry, but I don't have a ready URL for char class definitions to give to you. Also, can anyone remind me the official name for "predefined named character classes" (i.e. `[[:alpha:]]`) is (-;? Good luck to all.

Comment: To be clearer, I want to match `[[:graph:]]` characters when they are preceded by a single space.  Else I would match nothing at all.  I think if there is just a space with no valid graph characters after that, I would still get a match.

Comment: @Roger : `UTF-8` `[[:graph:]]` or `ASCII` `[[:graph:]]` ?  The latter matches 94 characters, the former matches some `260,015` code points according to `gawk 5.2.1`

Comment: `ASCII [[:graph:]]`

Comment: Awk states that graph represents characters that are both printable and visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So basically one or more graph characters preceded by space; or
> nothing (empty).

Base at this description I propose following pattern

```
(^$)|(^[[:space:]][[:graph:]]+$)
```

this does hold for empty line (`^$`) or (`|`) line which consist of single whitespace character followed by one-or-more (`+`) graph characters.

Comment: Could this also be adapted following some other preceding pattern.  Example `${ptrn}` or `${ptrn}[[:space:]][[:graph:]]+$`